# Trigger checking with not like statements

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Trying to create a trigger that doesnt let me insert into a table unless a employee is staff or manager. The following code compiles but when I try to test it by inserting some values I am not getting the required output the error pops up whenever I try to insert anything. When I have just Not Like 'Manager' or Not Like 'Staff' and not both of them combined, the trigger works fine. Any suggestions or see anything wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_check BEFORE
      INSERT ON handles FOR EACH row DECLARE empclass VARCHAR(10);
      BEGIN
        SELECT e.class INTO empclass FROM employee e WHERE e.empno = :new.empno;
        IF empclass NOT LIKE 'Manager' or 'Staff' THEN
          raise_application_error(-20003, ('Only a Staff Member or Manager Can Handle Orders'));
        END IF;
      END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the code you have posted cannot compile.  The line

```
IF empclass NOT LIKE 'Manager' or 'Staff' THEN
```

would be interpreted as

```
IF (empclass NOT LIKE 'Manager') or ('Staff') THEN
```

which would generate a PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type because `Staff` is not an expression that evaluates to a boolean.

Second, you don't appear to have any need to use the `LIKE` operator in this code.  You aren't using wild cards or expressions, you are simply testing for equality or inequality.  Use equality operators for that sort of thing.  You'd use `LIKE` if you want to compare against expressions with wild cards.

Third, you probably want to use a `NOT IN` here

```
IF empclass NOT IN ('Manager', 'Staff') THEN
```